# Periodic light rays in ellipse

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, reflection

I was just fiddling with GeoGebra when I found this: imagine a light ray in an elliptical mirror; whenever I choose a point $A$ on the ellipse and a positive integer $n$, I can adjust $B$ so that the ray starting from $A$ and going towards $B$ returns to $A$ and touches the ellipse in exactly $n$ points.
Here are some examples. 
[image]
[image]
[image]
The last picture shows 28 reflections.

First of all, is this true? If so, is it possible to prove it with not too advanced tools? Is this a peculiarity of the ellipse only, or there are other curves with the same property?

Comment: This is a very important and deep subject, with many many ramifications and active research. Look at keywords "elliptic billiard", "closed orbits"; unfortunately, many web ressources are at a research level; a first small introduction is given in the Wolfram site.

Comment: Are you sure about the $28$ reflections ?

Comment: The property must be true for any convex continuous curve with a continuous tangent direction. ($G^1$ continuity.)

Comment: I don't count $28$ reflections.

Comment: When the light beam comes back to $A$ it repeats the same path. The beam reflects 28 times, but you can see just the 8 sides of the polygonal path...

Comment: @Human: hem, in which circumstances is $28$ a multiple of $8$ ?

Comment: My intention was to show that when the beam hits $A$, it repeats the same polygon. Any number greater than 7 of reflections is sufficient to show that. See the answer below (history and comments too).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going out on a limb and suggesting that this is true and easy (which means it doesn't start addressing the really hard questions about billiards on elliptical tables).

I argue from continuity.

If you start at $A$ and go only a short distance to $B$ then you will bounce around a convex polygon and return to a point past $A$ in a finite number of steps. That point depends continuously on the position of $B$. The nearer $B$ to $A$ the more steps that will take. Now given $n$, imagine moving $B$ away until you reach the transition that just hits $A$ in $n$ steps.

I suspect that's the strategy the OP used to construct his examples in GeoGebra.

In fact, the ball will continue to follow this trajectory:

> On an elliptical billiard table, the envelope of a trajectory is a
>   smaller ellipse, a hyperbola, a line through the foci of the ellipse,
>   or a closed polygon (Steinhaus 1999, pp. 239 and 241; Wagon 1991).
>   (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Billiards.html)

(I found that in responding to the OP's comment below and edited question demonstrating the fact.)

---

Leaving this for historical reasons:

If this argument is wrong I'm sure a commenter will point that out. Then I can decide whether to delete it, or leave it as an instructive failure. If it's right it probably works for many smooth convex sets .

Comment: Thank you for you answer. By trying with GeoGebra it really seems that if the trajectory hits $A$ again (provided that the path doesn't cross itself) then it repeats the same polygon...

Comment: @Human See my edit.

Comment: The continuity argument is indeed enough to show that if $n$ reflections can lead you to either side of the target point, then you can reach it. But I am afraid that this isn't enough, as there could be "shadow areas" that cannot be reached at all. Think of a quarter circle where you "carve a hole" in one of the straight sides. Then it's impossible to reach points inside this hole from the center of the circle. So visibility after $n$ reflections should be discussed as well.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm not sure I am visualizing the figure you describe. If it's not convex then I agree with you. For the ellipse I believe the continuity argument (and smooth boundary) essentially implies visibility.

Comment: @EthanBolker: no the figure isn't convex. But continuity isn't enough to prove that any two points see each other after exactly $n$ reflections as this is a global property.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The question says that given $A$ you can find a $B$ that leads back to $A$ in $n$ steps - not that any $B$ will do. Local properties can imply global ones with the right hypotheses - e.g. lots of calculus.

Comment: @EthanBolker: this is my point: there could be some $A$ for which there is no such $B$.